# copying from one location to other

Tags: python

I am trying to copy from one location to other as below and running into following error,can anyone provide inputs as to how to overcome this?

```
import argparse
import shutil, errno

def copystuff(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    except OSError as exc: # python >2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        else: raise


def main ():
    source= "\\Terminal\workspace\username\nfc\AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB2.04.03.00.129.005"
    destination= "\\fosters\loc\LA\Build"
    copy_list=['\out\target\product\msm8226\obj\KERNEL_OBJ\vmlinux']
    for item in copy_list:
        src = source + item
        dest = destination + item
        copystuff(src,dest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Error:-

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\Terminal\workspace\username\nfc\AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB2.04.03.00.129.005\out\\target\\product\\msm8226\\obj\\KERNEL_OBJ\\vmlinux/*.*'
```

Comment: @Blender - its an accessible network path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use raw strings (or escape the slashes) when dealing with Windows paths:

```
source= r"\\Terminal\workspace\username\nfc\AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB2.04.03.00.129.005\\"
```

Otherwise, `\nfc` will be treated as `<newline>fc`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the path produced, shown in the error message. I think you forgot the backslash between the source and the item. ;)

Just add an backslash at the end of `source` and `destination`, or add one in the begginning of the item in the `copy_list`.

Comment: how to remove the double backslash "\\" in the path and make sure they are not used as escape characters

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Shutil before however you can use Os

```
    import os

    def copystuff(src, dst)
        os.system("cp " + src + " " + dst)

    copystuff("/example/directory/file.txt", "/other/directory")
```

The "os.system()" basically runs a terminal command. For windows, replace "cp" with "copy" as the command is different.